# Hide category from top navigation but show in side navigation?

Tags: category, navigation, filtered-nav

Is it possible to hide a child category from top navigation (selecting show in navigation as NO), but have it visible on side navigation in product listing pages?

Any extensions for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are attempting this on ce-1.7 or later this can be done easily.

Here is how I would do it.
I would [create a new category attribute](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/) (yes/no)  called `include_in_top_nav`.
Then override the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::_addCategoriesToMenu()` and add this code

```
if (!$category->getIncludeInTopNav()) {
    continue;
}
```

right after

```
if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
    continue;
}
```

This way you have a general way of managing all the categories in the top menu.